# Laravel 5.2: Authentication across sub-domains

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, subdomain

I'm trying to create a community website where users can register their own sub-domains to generate forums for gaming (guilds/clans/etc).

I have the system working to create and modify everything as needed, but the hitch I'm now running in to is adding the authentication.

As it stands a user can log in at the main site, however when they visit any of the sub-domains they aren't recognized as being logged in/authenticated. However if I go to my config/session.php and set

```
'session' => '.localhost'
```

I end up with a TokenMismatch error on line 67. I've got the project up on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aylnon/community)

Is this simply an error with how my routes are configured, or am I missing something much bigger?

This is my routes.php

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::auth();
Route::group(['domain' => '{alias}.localhost'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CommunitiesController@show');
    Route::get('/categories/create', 'CategoriesController@create');
    Route::get('/forums/create', 'ForumsController@create');
    Route::get('/{forum_id}', 'ForumsController@show');
    Route::get('/{forum_id}/post', 'PostsController@create');
    Route::get('/{forum_id}/{post_id}', 'PostsController@show');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::post('/categories/create', 'CategoriesController@store');
        Route::post('/forums/create', 'ForumsController@store');
        Route::post('/{forum_id}/post', 'PostsController@store');
        Route::post('/{forum_id}/{post_id}', 'RepliesController@store');
    });
});
Route::get('/', 'CommunitiesController@index');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/create', 'CommunitiesController@create');
    Route::post('/create', 'CommunitiesController@store');
});
```

Here is the view for the login:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And the authentication controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Both are stock from a fresh Laravel 5.2 installation.

Comment: Can you post your view and controller files?

Comment: If you make that change, you need to clear your browse cache. Also, if you're using `redis` or something of the sort, you need to flush the old sessions out of the database with `flushdb`. This is probably why you're experiencing the `TokenMismatch` error.

Comment: I went ahead and added in the view and controller. Ohgodwhy, I went ahead and cleared out my entire history, cookies and all, and still it's not working. I'm also not using any of the database engines for sessions, I'm using the file option.